# Should I write logic in fragment shader in this case?

Tags: glsl, webgl

I have 3 objects:

- *cube1*
- *cube2*
- *cube3*

I want to draw:

- *cube1* as *red(1,0,0)*,
- *cube2* with *texture1*
- *cube3* with *texture2*.

In fragment shader, I used

```c
FragColor = Color*texture2D(u_texture, TextureCoordinates)
```

as usual but this code also paints my 1st cube with the texture colors which I want it to be only red. So color is mixed up. My question is should I write a logic in fragment shader to separate these cases?

Comment: If you don't want to switch shaders, then create a 1x1 texture with a single (white) color and use it for the uniform colored cubes. Binding a texture is much "cheaper" than changing the program.

Comment: thank you... If you make a reply, I can mark this as an answer. Switching shaders is easier for me I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a 1x1 texture with a single (white) color and use it for the uniform colored cubes.
Binding and using this texture is much "cheaper" than changing the shader program:

```js
let whiteTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, whiteTexture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
              new Uint8Array([255,255,255,255]));
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
```

Note, the lookup to this texture (`texture2D(u_texture, TextureCoordinates)`) will always return `vec4(1.0)`.

If the texture is bound (to the texture unit which is assigned to `u_texture`), then

```c
FragColor = Color * texture2D(u_texture, TextureCoordinates);
```

will sets the same fragment color as

```c
FragColor = Color * vec4(1.0);
```